# Running a python script in Windows gives "Unable to Create Process Using ..." when python.exe set to 'run as administrator'

Tags: python, windows

I used to be able to call python scripts directly from the command line in Windows. e.g.:

> C:\SomeScript.py

But after setting the python executable to 'Run as Administrator' in the compatibility settings, I always get the cryptic error "Unable to Create Process using' ... followed by path of the python file I'm trying to run:

> Unable to create process using 'C:\python\python.exe "C:\SomeScript.py" '

I get the same error if I try and run the file from Explorer (albeit flashing on my screen briefly,  or if I run the script from the 'Send To' popup.

Comment: Asked and Answered as I didn't find this solution anywhere online.  The error message is a bit cryptic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by the Python executable being set to 'Run As Administrator.'  in the compatibility settings;  presumably because windows could not load the UAC form to escalate privileges.

There are two possible solutions.

1. Remove the 'Run as Administrator' setting
2. Pass the script's path as an argument to Python.exe rather than calling it directly, which allows windows to prompt for escalation correctly.

I.e.  Instead of

> c:\SomeScript.py

run

> c:\python\python.exe c:\SomeScript.py